# Codeigniter alternative for PDO setFetchMode

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, pdo

In Codeigniter, how can i fetch the result set from DB query into a model? In native PHP PDO engine i have something like:

```
$pdo->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, new className());
```

So i have a class:

```
class ClassName {
    private $id;
}
```

What i want is the result from db query to populate the class, so:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where("table", array("id" => 1));
$object = $query->row.....(new className());

echo $object->id;
// Shows 1
```

Thanks
Radu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you are trying to do.

Per the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html):

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('table', array('id' => 1));
$object = $query->row(0, 'Your_Class_name') // Class MUST be loaded prior to use
echo $object->id; // Shows 1
```